# Double secondary winding transformer/EMC problem

Tags: transformer

I'm using the IL-10-0002 a double secondary winding transformer that I Will connect in series.
I'm wondering if I will face EMC problem when connecting the scondary winding in series ? Do you have any layout recommandation ?

[image]

Comment: A transformer is "EMC passive", but of course what matters is how you use it, that you did not specify.  What signals are fed to the transformer, e.g. frequency, dV/dt or amplitude ...? then, which device nearby you think might be disturbed?  etc. etc.

Comment: The transformer is used to ensure galvanic isolation between two boards and the signal is a square wave (power signal)

Comment: I have asked a bit more than this, but no problem.

Comment: Are you fulfilling the requirements in creepage and clearance between primary and secondary if you cross the primary with your diagonal secondary connection?

Comment: That’s what I’m asking exactly  what are the requirements that I should fullify if I cross the primary with diagonal secondary connection ? how to avoid EMC problem ?